# How to represent the set of Integers including +- Infinity in Scala

Tags: scala

I have just started with Scala, and I'm trying to create a data type, which is a union of Integers and the special values +Infinity and -Infinity. I'm trying to figure out how to do this the most idiomatic way in Scala.

One option I've tried so far is by using a trait:

```
trait MySet
case object Infinity extends MySet 
case object NegInfinity extends MySet 
case class Value(value: Int) extends MySet
```

This seams to work, but I'm not sure if this is the smartest way of doing it. In the end, I want to use this to model algebraic structures such as Groups, Monoids, etc. with MySet as the carrier set. E.g. doing something like:

```
trait Monoid[T]:
    val zero: T
    def @+(x: T, y: T): T
```

Something in that direction.

Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: Other than making the `trait` `sealed` I don't see anything wrong, with your definition. Not sure what do you expect as an answer, why you don't simply try it and see what happens?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Luis said in the comment, make the `trait` `sealed` will make it so that the compiler will know what are the possible extentions of `MySet`

Otherwise, your monoid can be enriched with the following operations :

```
val mySetMonoid = new Monoid[MySet] {
  // 1) first the associative operation, which I guess would be +
  def op(a1: MySet, a2: MySet) = (a1, a2) match {
    case (Value(x), Value(y)) => x+y
    case (Value(_), Infinity) => Infinity
    case (Value(_), NegInfinity) => NegInfinity
    case (Infinity, Value(_)) => Infinity
    case (NegInfinity, Value(_)) => NegInfinity
    case (NegInfinity, Infinity) => throw new UnsupportedOperationException(..) 
        // here you need to be more specific
        // on how you want to handle +infinity 
        // and -infinity being added
  }
  // 2) then the definition of your zero in regard of the associative operation
  val zero = Value(0)
}
```